# How do I include jQuery file in CodeIgniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I would like to use jQuery inside my CodeIngiter Project. I dont know how to include the js file.

I would like to have something like below in my view

```
<script src='<?php echo base_url().APPPATH ?>js/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='<?php echo base_url().APPPATH ?>js/my-js.js'></script>
```

Comment: The APPPATH constant is a filesystem path, so it's unlikely to be useful here.

Comment: 403 error is coming it's mean that the folder from where u r getting ur js file is not included into your **.htaccess** so first include that folder then it will work

Comment: I feel sometime, higher rep people are gettnig so mean, i think its a perfectly useful question, STOP KEEP VOTING DOWN ON NEW PEOPLE! GOSH!

Comment: @Adam that's exactly what I feel like!

Comment: Did it eventually work out for you ? cause its not for me..

Comment: @wadie Had to do some htaccess updates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814851/how-do-i-include-jquery-file-in-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment11001362_8814966

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, create a folder to put it in. Then you could use a template system like [this one](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html).

This lets you add js files either globally in the main template, or by a controller/function basis using the syntax `$this->template->add_js('assets/js/jquery.js');`

Answer (score 4):

Codeigniter has a javascript class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html

You would load the jquery library through:

```
$this->load->library('jquery');
```

Then you can paste this into your head section of your view:

```
<?php echo $library_src;?>
<?php echo $script_head;?>
```

For additional javascript files, I typically create a resource folder in my application folder, then use the base_url function to link to the files like:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('resources/name-of-js-file.js');?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: As of Codeigniter 3 they've put up this notice: `This library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It has always been with an ‘experimental’ status and is now no longer supported. Currently only kept for backwards compatibility.` But your second solution I guess would still work across the board.

Answer (score 3):

The `base_url()` requires to load the helper 'url'.

In order to archive that go to `application/config/autoloader.php` and add it on the variable `$autoloader['helper']` like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Comment: check you $config['base_url']

Comment: There was no problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

add a new folder 'js' in your `application` folder and in your views add this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/name of your js file"></script>
```

Comment: The same reply here too. How do we handle the 403 Forbidden ?

Comment: Ok, I see editing the .htaccess file does it. Is this the way to do when using CodeIgniter ?

Answer (score 1):

You include the JS file like any other HTML output.

Refer to where your JS is located (say its /js from root) and then in your `<head></head>` portion add the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I keep getting 403 Forbidden. How do we handle it ?

Comment: Nope,should be like this
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>