# How do I include jQuery file globally in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

How to include the jQuery file in CodeIgniter which can be accessible to the whole project.
Controller, Model, view and any other directory like Config, etc.?

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814851/how-do-i-include-jquery-file-in-codeigniter) address your question?

Comment: @Rooney Suggests this lets you add js files either globally in the main template, or by a controller/function basis using the syntax `$this->template->add_js('assets/js/jquery.js');` More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814851/how-do-i-include-jquery-file-in-codeigniter.

Comment: Also, try adding what you've tried and why that didnt work as expected.

Comment: While I believe this is doable, why would you want to be able to use jQuery inside a Controller or Model? Best way to do this in a view is to have a view that handles your <head> contents and just load it before your content view.

Answer (score 3):

With Codeigniter javascript class:

Docs: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html

You would load the jquery library through:

```
$this->load->library('jquery');
```

Updated, this line load jquery by default:

```
$this->load->library('javascript');
```

In your application/config.php or in config/javascript.php, you can config the path to your jquery.js file, like this:

```
$config['javascript_location'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/themes/js/jquery/';
$config['javascript_ajax_img'] = 'images/ajax-loader.gif';
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: Try with $this->load->library('javascript/jquery');

Comment: now its not giving error, but jquery is not working, this appears in console "jQuery is not defined OR $ is not defined"

Comment: I don't recommend using the codeigniter javascript class. It's mentioned in the docs that it's experimental, so that could be why you're having issues. I mentioned in your original question that you should just include it in the view as a special <head> view loaded before your content (I do this ALL the time, as do a lot of other projects). The jQuery lib functions provided by CI is a cool idea in concept in keeping with the CI conventions, but still.

Comment: actually i have multiple controllers thats why i am looking for method to include once at all. just like autoload .....

Comment: You'd only ever use it in your view, right? Again, make your life easy and create something like a header.php view that includes it for you, then just $this->load->view('header');$this->load->view('content');